# php add days to strftime

Tags: php, date, strftime

I need to print the Italian time from now to 30 days in this format `2013-03-11#11 Mar | Mon`

I've found that the Date function don't return the italian translation so I'm using [strftime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php).

but how can I add days to [strftime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)?

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'it_IT');
for($i=0; $i<30; $i++){
    echo $date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('now + '.$i.' days'));
    echo " # ";
    echo $date_string = strftime("%d %b | %a" );
    }
```

Comment: I dont understand the question. At the moment it is printing "2013-03-11 # 11 Mar | Lun" for 30 days into the future. What more do you want from the code?

Comment: Try remove the "now" from strtotime!

Comment: the first echo is correct, the second print today(30 times), not the days from today to 30 days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this :

```
strftime("%d %b | %a",strtotime($date))
```

This will display the month and day.

Answer (score 2):

This code seems to solve your problem:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, 'it_IT');
for($i=0; $i<30; $i++){
    echo $date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime('now + '.$i.' days'));
    echo " # ";
    echo $date_string = strftime( "%d %b | %a", strtotime('now + '.$i.' days') ) . "<br>";
}
```

The problem you were having is that, strftime, was using the default date, which is today. Looking at the documentation, http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php, you can specify a timestamp for it to use instead, which is your future date (now +$i), as the second parameter.

Enjoy!